# Why does the image of $ord_p$ form an additive subgroup of $(1/n)\mathbb Z$?

Tags: group-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $K$ be a field extension of the p-adic rationals $\mathbb Q_p$.
The image of $K^\times$ under the valuation map $ord_p(x)=-\frac 1 n\log_p|\mathbb N_{K/\mathbb Q_p}(x)|_p$ is contained in $(1/n)\mathbb Z = \{x ∈ Q| nx ∈ \mathbb Z\}$, where $n=[K:\mathbb Q_p]$.

> The image is an additive subgroup of $(1/n)\mathbb Z$ so it’s of the form $(1/e)\mathbb Z$ for an integer $e$ dividing $n$.

Why is that right? What do we know about the existence of, say, an inverse to any of these subgroup's elements?

Comment: If you *know* that $\operatorname{ord}_p$ is a *valuation* map (in particular, $\operatorname{ord}_p(xy)=\operatorname{ord}_p(x)+\operatorname{ord}_p(y)$ for $x,y\in K^{\times}$) then this should be trivial - say, the inverse to $\operatorname{ord}_p(x)$ is just $\operatorname{ord}_p(x^{-1})$. What's causing the question?

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks for the reply. How do we know that this inverse is contained in the _image_ $(1/e) \mathbb Z$? couldn't there be $x \in K^\times$ s.t. $ord_p(x^{-1})\notin (1/e) \mathbb Z$? or $x,y \in K^\times$ s.t. $ord_p(xy)\notin \mathbb Z$?

Comment: I'll edit here because I can't edit previous comment:  
Couldn't there be $x\in K^\times$ s.t. $ord_p(x)\in (1/e)\mathbb Z$ but $ord_p(x^{-1})\notin (1/e)\mathbb Z$? or $x,y\in K^\times$ s.t. $ord_p(x), ord_p(y)\in (1/e)\mathbb Z$ but $ord_p(xy)\notin (1/e)\mathbb Z$?

Comment: The image consists of *all* numbers $\operatorname{ord}_p(x), x\in K^{\times}$ *by definition* - as $xy\in K^{\times}$, $x^{-1}\in K^{\times}$, etc. for $x,y\in K^{\times}$, it will *automatically* contain $\operatorname{ord}_p(xy)$, $\operatorname{ord}_p(x^{-1})$ and the like.

Comment: Seems so obvious now.. Thank you :)

Comment: @metamorphy If you wanted to submit an answer, I’d happily +1

Answer (score 0):

To get this off the "unanswered" list, this comment by user metamorphy (May 14, 2019) answers it:

> The image consists of *all* numbers $ord_p(x), x \in K^\times$ *by definition* - as $xy \in K^\times, x^{−1} \in K^\times$, etc. for $x,y \in K^\times$, it will *automatically* contain $ord_p(xy), ord_p(x^{−1})$ and the like.